# Time complexity of inserting a node in a sorted linked list

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list, time-complexity, sortedlist

What is the time complexity of inserting a node in a sorted linked list in Java? Is there an algorithm with complexity less than *O(n)*?

Comment: Usually not, unless there you have references to several nodes in the list.

Comment: With only O(1) references into the list (e.g. head + tail), then no.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth there is no pointers in Java.

Comment: @Omore - NullPointerException disagrees ;)  (Didn't notice that this was marked Java...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you have is a linked links and you're starting from the head, in the worst case you have to iterate over the entire list to find the insertion point. This gives O(n) worst-case time.

Something like a [skiplist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list) could give O(log n) insertion. However, that's a different data structure to what you're asking about (and so are trees etc).